# Не получается создать кастомный TextView

Tags: android

Не получается сделать кастомный `TextView`

Создал класс `CustomTextView`

```
public class CustomTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        UiUtil.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs,
                R.styleable.ru_myapp_fairytalesforchildren_utils_CustomTextView,
                R.styleable.ru_myapp_fairytalesforchildren_utils_CustomTextView_customFont);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        UiUtil.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs,
                R.styleable.ru_myapp_fairytalesforchildren_utils_CustomTextView,
                R.styleable.ru_myapp_fairytalesforchildren_utils_CustomTextView_customFont);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```

Класс `UiUtil`

```
public class UiUtil {
    public static final String TAG = "UiUtil";

    public static void setCustomFont(View textViewOrButton, Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs, int[] attributeSet, int fontId) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attributeSet);
        String customFont = a.getString(fontId);
        setCustomFont(textViewOrButton, ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    private static boolean setCustomFont(View textView, Context ctx, String asset) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(asset))
            return false;
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = getFont(ctx, asset);
            if (textView instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) textView).setTypeface(tf);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: " + asset, e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static final Hashtable<String, SoftReference<Typeface>> fontCache = new Hashtable<String, SoftReference<Typeface>>();

    public static Typeface getFont(Context c, String name) {
        synchronized (fontCache) {
            if (fontCache.get(name) != null) {
                SoftReference<Typeface> ref = fontCache.get(name);
                if (ref.get() != null) {
                    return ref.get();
                }
            }

            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                    c.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/" + name
            );
            fontCache.put(name, new SoftReference<Typeface>(typeface));

            return typeface;
        }
    }
}
```

Создал атрибут в res/values/attr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ru.myapp.fairytalesforchildren.utils.CustomTextView">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Использую в разметке так

```
<ru.myapp.fairytalesforchildren.utils.CustomTextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:maxLines="2"
android:text="@string/item_title"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:font="LaMonaKidsBaseLayerTwo.ttf"/>
```

Выдает ошибку

> Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
>   C:\Android\Projects\Fairytalesforchildren\app\src\main\res\layout\item.xml
>   Error:error: 'LaMonaKidsBaseLayerTwo.ttf' is incompatible with
>   attribute ru.myapp.fairytalesforchildren:font (attr) reference [weak].
>   Error:error: 'LaMonaKidsBaseLayerTwo.ttf' is incompatible with
>   attribute ru.myapp.fairytalesforchildren:font (attr) reference [weak].
>   Error:'LaMonaKidsBaseLayerTwo.ttf' is incompatible with attribute
>   ru.myapp.fairytalesforchildren:font (attr) reference [weak].
>   Error:'LaMonaKidsBaseLayerTwo.ttf' is incompatible with attribute
>   ru.myapp.fairytalesforchildren:font (attr) reference [weak].
>   Error:failed linking file resources.
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > Failed to execute aapt Information:BUILD FAILED in 5s Information:9 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete output in
> >     console

Не могу понять в чем причина. Помогите исправить пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вы же задекларировали атрибут

```
<attr name="customFont" format="string" />
```

А пытаетесь использовать в разметке

```
app:font="LaMonaKidsBaseLayerTwo.ttf"
```

Отсюда и ошибка:

> Error:error: 'LaMonaKidsBaseLayerTwo.ttf' is incompatible with attribute ru.myapp.fairytalesforchildren:font (attr) reference [weak].

Comment: А как правильно писать?

Comment: app: customFont="LaMonaKidsBaseLayerTwo.ttf"

Comment: ой вот я ступил. Спасибо